# How can we use same thread object multiple times

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, threadpool, qthread

We want to call start method 4 times but we do not want to create thread object for each time.
Is it possible to create one object of thread and call same method 4 times.

we tried different ways but new initialization require for every time when we are calling method.

Comment: You've tagged both [qthread] and [pthreads].  If you're asking about Qt's `QThread` class, then the latter is inappropriate and misleading.  If you're *not* talking about `QThread`, then the former is even more inappropriate and misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

First, rename your `MyThread::run()` to `void MyThread::old_run()`

Then, write a new `MyThread::run()` as follows:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
   for( int i = 0;  i < 4;  i++ )
      old_run();
}
```